# Understanding the proof of "Archimedean property $\Rightarrow$ every monotone bounded sequence is Cauchy"

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Here is a proof:
[Least upper bound property implies Cauchy completeness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953935/least-upper-bound-property-implies-cauchy-completeness/1954186#1954186).
I do understand the construction of the subsequence, but how can I formally conclude that the sequence we constructed is unbounded by definition? 
The definition should be: $(\forall s\in F^+)(\exists x_{n_k})(|x_{n_k}|>s)$

May be a method is take an extra step to show that $(n\epsilon)$ is unbounded. But once I prove it, how can I use it to conclude that $x_{n_k}$ is unbounded? May I ask for a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the construction of the sequence. We have a subsequence where:

$$x_{n_{k+1}} - x_{n_k} > \epsilon$$

This means that:

$$x_{n_k} > x_{n_1}+(k-1)\epsilon$$

Now suppose we had an upper bound $s$ we only have to know that there's a $k$ such that $x_{n_1} + (k-1)\epsilon > s$ to get a contradiction which is where the Archimedian property comes into play.

We know that there's an $l$ such that $l > (s - x_{n_1})/\epsilon$ ($\epsilon\ne0$). Putting $k = l+1$ we immediately get $x_{n_1} + (k-1)\epsilon > L$ since $\epsilon>0$, which contradicts the assumption that it was bounded so we conclude that the subsequence is unbounded.