# How does the least upper bound property imply the Archimedean property?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953935/least-upper-bound-property-implies-cauchy-completeness) post gives the incomplete proof of the following theorem:
In any ordered field F, the following are equivalent:

1. F has the least upper bound property
2. F is complete and has the Archimedean property.

I did not understand how (1) implies the Archimedean property of F. What if we have a metric space that does not have any real numbers? In that case, the Archimedean property can not be applied.

Comment: How is a metric space with no elements a field? Fields have (at least in my definition) at least two elements. An ordered field will have at least countably many elements, thanks to $1+n>n$. In other words, it is quite easy to see that any ordered field has a copy of $\mathbb Q$ embedded in it.

Comment: @DonThousand I asked what if the space does not have any real numbers (not elements). The Archimedean property talks about a natural number. My question is what if there is no natural number in the field (but instead some other elements)

Comment: you could add an element of the field to itself $n$ times, where $n\in\mathbb N$

Answer (score 0):

The part of the answer you are referencing that proves that the l.u.b. property implies the Archimedean property is this:

> **Archimedean Property:** For every real $x$ there is an integer $n$ such that $n>x$
>
> *Proof:* If this is not the case, integers would be bounded by some $x$.

But it's also worth noting that before this part, the answerer wrote:

> To simplify discussion, we assume that the order field is $\mathbb{R}$.

The original answerer is suggesting here that integers being bounded above by some $x$ is a contradiction in any ordered field, they just use $\mathbb R$ to keep their answer tidier (basically, the same argument can be made in any ordered field, with $x$ instead just being a member of that field).

The result seems pretty intuitive, but the reliance on the l.u.b. property comes from the fact that if the set of integers, $\langle 1\rangle\subset F$ ($F$ denotes the whole ordered field) is bounded above by some $x$, then $\langle 1\rangle$ (being nonempty as it contains, e.g. $0$) has an l.u.b., $u$. The reason this is a contradiction is that by the property of l.u.b.s, we should be able to choose some integer $n\in \langle 1\rangle$ that is $>u-1$ (specifically, as $F$ is an ordered field, $u-1$ is $<u$. As $u$ is the l.u.b. of $\langle 1\rangle$, it follows that $u-1$ cannot be an upper bound of $\langle 1\rangle$, hence we may choose this $n$). But now (as $F$ is an ordered field), we have $n+1>u$. Clearly $n+1$ is also in $\langle 1\rangle$, and now the contradiction should be clear ($u$ is both an upper bound of $\langle 1\rangle$ and not an upper bound of $\langle 1\rangle$).

Note that in the previous paragraph no mention of the 'metric' (if there even is one) of $F$ was made. The only properties used were those $F$ possessed as an ordered field.