Prove F is an Archimedean field
The definition of the Archimedean field in Robert Bartle's "Elements of Analysis" is given by for each element $x$ in F there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x < n$.
Problem: Prove that if $F$ is an ordered field in which every non-empty set which has an upper bound also has a supremum, then F is an Archimedean field.
Proof: By contradiction, suppose that F is not Archimedean. Then this implies that there is an element $x \in F$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \geq n$.
Define a set $S =\Bbb N$. Then $1 \in S$, so $S$ is non-empty. Moreover, $S$ is bounded above by $x$. So, $S$ has an upper bound.
By the hypothesis, let $u =\sup(S)$. Now, it is true that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there is an element $m \in S$ such that $u-\epsilon < m$. Set $\epsilon = 1$.  Then $u-1 < m\implies u < m+1$. Since $m\in S$ then $m+1 \in S$ because $S=\Bbb N.$ So, we found an element $m+1$ in $S$ such that $m+1 > u$. Contradiction to the definition of the supremum, hence the set $S$ has no supremum. And this contradicts to our hypothesis that any non-empty subset of $F$ which has an upper bound also has a supremum.
Thus, $F$ is Archimedean.
Question: Would the construction of such a set work in this proof?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This has now become a duplicate of (for instance) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977074 For other relevant posts, see https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=upper+bound+property+Archimedean
